# Repopulating birthday dropdown

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am not able to figure out how to repopulate my birthday drop down helper in CodeIgniter when the validation fails and the page reloads. I am trying to use `set_value('field_name')` It's a little more involved than my other drop downs because there are three elements involved.

My code is available [here](https://gist.github.com/a1c8428675d890d6b5f4)

thanks in advance

Here are the validation rules

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('relation', 'Relation', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'Location', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules($birthdate, 'Birthday', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'Gender', 'trim|required');
```

Comment: I have a feeling something is missing. Where are your validation rules? `set_value()` often does not work if at least some kind of validation rule is applied to the element.

Comment: @Brendan I just added them. Sorry, forgot to put those in the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a stripped down version of what I use to validate birthdate (and repopulate the dropdowns). FYI I have some logic in here you may want to remove.

Validation Rules:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rule('birthdate-month','Birthdate Month','required|is_natural_no_zero|greater_than[0]|less_than[13]');
$this->form_validation->set_rule('birthdate-day','Birthdate Day','required|is_natural_no_zero|greater_than[0]|less_than[32]');
$this->form_validation->set_rule('birthdate-year','Birthdate Year','required|is_natural_no_zero|greater_than[1930]|less_than['.(date("Y") - 18).']');
```

Controller:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
    $birthdate = array(
        $this->form_validation->set_value('birthdate-year'),
        $this->form_validation->set_value('birthdate-month'),
        $this->form_validation->set_value('birthdate-day')
    );

    $data = array(
        'birthdate' => implode("-", $birthdate)
    );
}

// Then pass $data to your model and do whatever you want, i.e.:
$this->user_model->update_user($data);
```

Then the PHP/HTML in the view:

```
<select name="birthdate-month" id="birthdate-month">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php foreach($months as $month_number => $month_name) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $month_number; ?>" <?php echo set_select('birthdate-month', $month_number); ?>><?php echo $month_name; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>

<select name="birthdate-day" id="birthdate-day">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php echo set_select('birthdate-day', $i); ?>><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>

<select name="birthdate-year" id="birthdate-year">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php for($i=(date("Y") - 18); $i>=1930; $i--) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php echo set_select('birthdate-year', $i); ?>><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Also FYI, `$months` is an array:

```
array(
    '01' => 'January',
    '02' => 'February',
    '03' => 'March',
    '04' => 'April',
    '05' => 'May',
    '06' => 'June',
    '07' => 'July',
    '08' => 'August',
    '09' => 'September',
    '10' => 'October',
    '11' => 'November',
    '12' => 'December'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation tell :

> **set_select()**
>
> If you use a  menu, this function permits you to display the menu item that was selected. The first parameter must contain the name of the select menu, the second parameter must contain the value of each item, and the third (optional) parameter lets you set an item as the default (use boolean TRUE/FALSE).

**Example:**

```
<select name="myselect">
<option value="one" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'one', TRUE); ?> >One</option>
<option value="two" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'two'); ?> >Two</option>
<option value="three" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'three'); ?> >Three</option>
</select>
```